# How to Hide Keyboard in Android from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, keyboard, hide, android-broadcastreceiver

In my app, there is one BroadcastReceiver for Screen off and Screen on, and if the keyboard is open by user in any app like whatsapp, skype, facebook messanger, I want to hide that keyboard when user lock the screen/unlock the screen.

The Key guard is disabled and I have put my custom screen there also.

Can any one help me out please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help and efforts you have put, but it is not working :-(